# Fatal error: Class 'Vokuro\Auth\MongoDate' not found in

Tags: php, mongodb, namespaces, phalcon

I'm building an application using Mongo and Phalcon. I'm trying to copy the user login, creation, etc from Vokuro, but I've run into a small problem:

I've copied the Auth library and I'm editing parts of it so it works with Mongo. In the function registerUserThrottling I'm replacing the timestamps for Mongo Dates, like this:

```
$failedLogin->attempted = new MongoDate(time());
```

But I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Vokuro\Auth\MongoDate' not found in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/playerm8/app/library/Auth/Auth.php
>   on line 88

I'm sure Mongo is installed properly because I use it in the same app and I even use the same MongoDate function in one of the controllers without any issues.

The problem here is that Phalcon is looking for the function in the namespace Vokuro\Auth.

The question is: how can I use MongoDate from inside library/Auth/Auth.php in Vokuro https://github.com/phalcon/vokuro/blob/master/app/library/Auth/Auth.php

Comment: Wild guess, but did you try `\MongoDate`?

Comment: I should have tried that and I think it would have worked. But I've gotten rid of the namespace and made it work a different way. Thanks for the effort @Timothy hopefully somebody else finds this useful

Answer (score 0):

What is the path of your code?
If it is in /app/ then something like:

```
use library\Auth\Auth
```

But that is assuming you have already loaded / autoloaded the library somewhere as the programme starts.

Comment: I've loaded the namespace in app/config/loader.php and the first line of code in app/library/Auth/Auth.php is - namespace Vokuro\Auth; - not sure where you are suggesting to add - use library\Auth\Auth - ? If the Auth library works properly, the problem is that Mongo functions don't work.

Comment: Oh.  OK.  Above the class where you are trying to Instantiate it.

Comment: I just looked again.  Do you want to instantiate the MongoDateTime() in  vokuro/app/library/Auth/Auth.php

Comment: If so then you need to be sure you are importing the correct class and or namespace. Then it may be worth trying to use it as a static class like l  
`$obj = new library/Auth/Auth;`
`$failedLogin->attempted = $obj->MongoDate(time());`
Its a bit difficult to work out with out the full code base locally.